# Hide modal by ID when there are more modals

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with several modals and I open them by unique ID, like this:

```
%a{"data-toggle" => "modal", href: "#modal-123", role: "button"}
%a{"data-toggle" => "modal", href: "#modal-456", role: "button"}
```

This works fine, but the problem is closing a specific modal. By default this is done by this:

```
.modal.fade{:style => "display: none;", :tabindex => "-1", id: "modal-123"}
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
      .modal-body
      .modal-footer
        %button.btn.btn-default{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} Close
```

But this doesn't work because it doesn't know which of the modals to close. How can I make it close the modal with the specific ID?

Comment: Is there any preprocessor involved? You might want to tag that to the question, or post plain HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the data-dismiss attribute. then add

```
$('.btn.btn-default').click(function(){
   $(this).modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `modal(hide)` method on this.

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

Answer (score 1):

Through javascript, you can close specific modal by ID using `.modal('hide')` method. Like:

```
$('#modal-456').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the code below it will help.
Basically, on click you can get click event in which the particular modal 
will get hide.

```
$('#your-modal-id').on('click', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```